# pub run build_runner build has error (66)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

hey guys i have error after using command : `flutter pub run build_runner build`

error message :

```
C:\Users\matin\AndroidStudioProjects\mosito>flutter pub run build_runner build
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "C:\Users\matin\Documents\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\async-2.8.1".
pub finished with exit code 66
```

i try `flutter pub upgrade` and a lot of things from google but problem not fixed
NOTE: im new to flutter i want use this command for making `.g.dart` file for my models thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think may be you are not in your project directory. Suppose you have a project name A in myfolder in C drive of your computer. First goto  myfolder with terminal. after that try below code to build the project...

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Comment: im in my project DIR , i run this command and i get : 

```Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "C:\Users\matin\Documents\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\async-2.8.1".
pub finished with exit code 66
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Your Terminal and Run

```
flutter doctor
```

if it is showing
Could not find "flutter"

Then you need to install flutter Correctly You Can check :

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows

Comment: ```[√] Flutter (Channel dev, 2.9.0-0.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.2237], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)

[√] Chrome - develop for the web

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all ...

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)

[√] Connected device (3 available)```